# Laravel guardar datos en una tabla y recuperar la Id de ese registro para guardar en otra tabla

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola estoy tratando de guardar los datos en la tabla producto y una vez hecho esto necesito seleccionar la id de ese registro de producto para guardarla en una tabla detalle_producto, ¿como puedo realizarlo?

esto es lo que tengo en el controllador que solo me sirve para guardar en producto

```
 public function store(Request $request)
        {   
            $datos=request()->except('_token');
    
          
            producto::insert($datos);
            return redirect('producto');
        
        }
```

Comment: recuperar ese id para utilizarlo en otro insert

Answer (score 0):

Para poder recuperar el último `id` insertado en tabla, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$ultimoId = producto::latest('id')->first()->id;
```

Lo que estamos haciendo:

- Obtener los registros asociados de la tabla asociada al modelo `producto`
- Ordenar descendentemente por la columna `id` a través del método `latest`
- Con `first` limitamos la cantidad de registros a 1
- Con `->id` le indicamos que solo nos retorne el id de ese único registro deseado

De esta manera obtendriamos en la variable `$ultimoId` el último id registrado, le pasamos como argumento a latest la columna id ya que originalmente el acomodo lo hace por la columna de `created_at`.

Por ejemplo yo desde un ejemplo local, ejecutando esta consulta desde *tinker* obtengo algo así:

```
>>> App\Model::latest('id')->first()->id;
=> 3
>>>
```

Ahora podrás recuperar esa variable en un `create` donde almacenes dicho resultado

Teniendo ya guardado el ID en una variable tienes dos opciones

- Crea una instancia del modelo que utilizarás para almacenar este id en la otra tabla
- Puedes invocar el método create para tener una sintaxis más simple, solo recuerda que si es este último agregues las propiedades que pueden llenarse o asignarse [masivamente](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) en el modelo

Es decir:

```
OtroModelo::create([
    'columna' => $ultimoId
 ]);
```

Indicamos por medio de un array asociativo la clave será columna y el valor será el ID recuperado

Comment: para esta solucion es necesario aplicar un  protected $fillable en el modelo?

Comment: cargo esto $dc_id=$request->input('dc_id'); y comprobe con un var_dump que trae el dato que debe traer y asi guardo...detalle_productos::create([
            'dc_id'=>$dc_id,
            'pro_id' => $pro_id
         ]);... pero me envia este error... SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: el valor null para la columna «dc_id» viola la restricción not null DETAIL: La fila que falla contiene (5, null, 23). (SQL: insert into "detalle_productos" ("pro_id") values (23) returning "dp_id").. en el create se pierde el valor de dp_id

Comment: Error mio olvide agregar el dc_id al  $fillable

Comment: Con ese cambio ya te funcionó? @Tarenk77

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar uno de estos métodos

el primero es muy parecido al que tienes actualmente pero devuelve el id insertado
`$id=DB::table('producto')->insertGetId( $datos);`

el segundo es un create y este devuelve el objeto completo creado y de ahi puedes sacar el id entre las otras propiedades del objeto

```
$data = producto::create($datos); 
$data->id;
```

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias ahora lo hago, solo pensé que estaba auto explicado

Comment: la id se llama pro_id y con la primera opcion me devuelve un error diciendo que la columna id no existe

Comment: Y la segunda, pudiste probarla?

Comment: la segunda me resulto, queria ver si me salia con la primera

Comment: Qué bueno @Tarenk 77